# jQuery Insert Text at Character in Div

Tags: jquery, text, html

I have a `div` like

```
<div class="mycooldiv">
    bunch of text is in here and for example some # and some other cool #
</div>
```

How can I insert text at the `#` - where the `#` could be at any position ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using regular expressions to replace the # with the text you want to insert.

```
var $div = $('.mycooldiv');
$div.text($div.text().replace(/#/, 'Text to insert here');
```